# EF Fluent API - Combination of Shadow Property, IsRequired(True) and DeleteBehavior.NoAction / Restrict

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have encountered the familiar Multiple Cascade Paths issue:

**Parent Config:**

```
builder.HasMany(p => p.Persons)
    .WithOne(p => p.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey("ParentId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.HasMany(p => p.Places)
    .WithOne(p => p.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey("ParentId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

**Place Config:**

```
// Nothing Special
```

**Person Config:**

```
builder.HasOne(p => p.Place)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("PlaceId")
    .IsRequired(true)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

- If I have a Person then it must be related to a Place.
- I understand that I need to use DeleteBehavior.NoAction on the Person > Place relationship because the Parent is already taking care of DeleteBehaviour.Cascade on the Place and Person records, so another Cascade from Place to Person will cause a multiple cascade path.
- I need to add IsRequired(true) because "PlaceId" is a shadow property added by EF (shadow property gets nullable by default), rather than a declared property on the Person class.  (I don't want the domain model to need PlaceId on the entity itself).

The problem is that, despite specifying NoAction delete behavior, it looks like the "IsRequired(true)" is overriding this and forcing:

```
onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade
```

on the migration.  Same result if I use Restrict.

I understand that using NoAction could lead to a FK violation in case a Place that is referenced by a Person is deleted, but I can manage that in my EF Graph.  It seems that what I'm hoping for is perfectly reasonable.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` instead of `NoAction`?

Comment: I have indeed.  Both .NoAction and .Restrict get overridden to .Cascade by using the "IsRequired(true)".